# Google Maps - center map on marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code for placing several markers on a google map.

What I now want to do is when the user clicks on a marker it zooms in and then centers the map to the marker position (this is the bit that's not working - towards the end of the code in the setMarkers function).

Any ideas?

```
var infowindow = null;
var sites = [];
var partsOfStr = [];
var partsOfStr2 = [];
var bounds;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select[id*='coordList']").find("option").each(function () {
        partsOfStr = $(this).val().split(',');
        partsOfStr2 = $(this).text().split('^');
        sites.push([partsOfStr2[0], parseFloat(partsOfStr[0]), parseFloat(partsOfStr[1]), partsOfStr[2], partsOfStr2[1], partsOfStr2[2], partsOfStr2[3], partsOfStr[3], partsOfStr[4], partsOfStr[5]]);
    });
    initialize();
});

function initialize() {
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.57951, -4.41387),
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    setMarkers(map, sites);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "loading..."
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(54.57951, -4.41387));
        map.setZoom(6);
    });

}



function setMarkers(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            html: "<div class='mapDesc'>content here...</div>"
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); // NOT WORKING!!!!!!!
            map.setZoom(10);
        });

        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does `sites` look like before `initialize()` is called?

Comment: Sites is an array with all the info for the marker positions and infowindow data. It's definitely not this that's causing the problem though

Answer (score 18, accepted):

marker is left pointing to the last marker added. Either use function closure or "this" like you did for the infowindow:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.html);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
        map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); 
        map.setZoom(10);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (evt) {
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
            map.setCenter(evt.latLng); 
            map.setZoom(10);
        });
```

that will working in my own app